# How do I query a list of custom objects in apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object

How do I query a list of custom objects in an apex trigger?

In the console, the following query returns the 2 objects I have created.

```
select Id, QueueId__c, Counter__c from QueueCount__c
```

When i try to run the same query in an apex trigger for a lead insert

```
List<QueueCount__c> listOfQueueCounters = [select Id, QueueId__c, Counter__c from QueueCount__c];
```

The query doesn't return any values. The query is done outside of any loop and looking through the execution log I find the following:

```
13:56:26:411 SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN [29]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, QueueId__c, Counter__c FROM QueueCount__c
13:56:26:412 SOQL_EXECUTE_END [29]|Rows:0
```

Comment: Is it possible this is being run in a sandbox with no data present?

Comment: it is in a sandbox, but i added the data. the console query editor runs the same query but returns the records I want.

Comment: are the both users same who are executing both queries

Comment: I assume it is. I'm running a Test Class for the Apex trigger through the console. The user in the log says the my user (admin) but uncertain if the test class runs using that user. I'll review the custom objects permissions to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use seeAllData if you don't have to, and I believe most SObjects in Salesforce can have test data built for them in most cases. You need to build your object that you are expecting, I recommend looking around for why you shouldn't use `seeAllData` if not absolutely necessary.

I only added to the two fields here that you have in your query, I don't know if the fields are integers, strings or even auto numbers so you may have to update.

```
QueueCount__c queueCount = new QueueCount__c()
queueCount.QueueId__c = 1234;
queueCount.Counter__c = 5;
insert queueCount;
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I was running the apex trigger through a test class with

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false)
```

Changing the seeAllData to **true** allowed my test class to query the custom object properly.

Comment: That is not correct, well it is.. but you shouldnt do that

Comment: How do I get the query to work if I don't?

Comment: You have to build your data, I wrote a quick answer

Comment: i understand. thanks, I'll make yours the correct answer.